# To deinstall as equialent to dismantle

Tags: single-word-requests

To deinstall - is it correct to use as equialent to dismantle for equipment?

Comment: "Uninstall" is more idiomatic in the tech sector.

Comment: They differ in focus. You disassemble or dismantle the higher assembly by deinstalling/uninstalling/removing components. *Deinstall* tends to be used to refer to plant equipment. It suggests careful removal, preservation of all systems, and crating, making it ready to be reinstalled elsewhere.

Comment: You might want to read [the description of the [single-word-requests\] tag](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) — you seem to be using it incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, this was my understanding too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deinstall something is to remove it from its location. To dismantle it is to take it apart. I would need to deinstall the carburetor from my model A's engine before I could dismantle it for rebuilding.

Comment: Absolutely, so plus 1. Also on moving home, for example, you might _deinstall_ the washing machine from the one you were leaving and _reinstall_ it in the one you were going to without removing any parts from it all. However if it went wrong some months later someone would have to _dismantle_ it in order to repair it. Depending on the fault they might be able to _dismantle_ it enough to fix it without _deinstalling_ it.

Answer (score 0):

The "de" qualifier implies something about reversing the "install" so it might be understood as a synonym for dismantle but it's quite a mouthful isn't it?

I'd suggest that although it is understandable it is [not common usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dismantle%2Cdeinstall&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdismantle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeinstall%3B%2Cc0) and would sound a little odd.